# Where to define the maximum number of connections in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, data-connections

I want to limit the number of users per database in a multi tenant environment. But there are three levels of max connections and I should be grateful for any advice.

**Level 1 Entire Server**

By editing the config for Postgresql I can set the Max connection for the all databases on a server

```
postgresql.conf = max_connections = 100
```

**Level 2 Per database**

I can select and set the database connection limit per database:

```
SELECT datconnlimit FROM pg_database
```

**Level 3 Per role**

I can select and set the role connection limit per "user":

```
SELECT rolconnlimit FROM pg_roles
```

My questions are

1. If the max_connections in postgresql.conf is 100, will it be max connections of all databases regardless database and role settings? e.g. 100 databases can only have 1 connection each simultaneously?
2. Where is the best place to limit max connections. At the database level or at the role level?
3. Anything other to be considered?

TIA for any advice or clue!

Comment: 1) is clear [from the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS) (absolute limit for the whole server). And the rest depends on your use case.

Comment: dhke: "And the rest depends on your use case". Depends on what? Any hint?

Comment: Are there actually multiple DB users? (e.g. big web application with single DB user), Do you have multiple databases? Are those databases used by different users? In (common) case with single user, single DB, `max_connections`, `datconnlimit`, and `rolconnlimit` are all the same, governed by the lowest one.

Comment: Yes, there is multiple databases per server and normally one user per database. So does this mean that I can set _rolconnlimit_ to 10 the role and _datconnlimit_ to -1 on the database. And the max connections is handled by the role? Then the  postgres admin could connect to the database without problem?

Comment: Note that there's also [`superuser_reserved_connections`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html). `datconnlimit` and `rolconnlimit` are not enforced for superusers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `max_connections` minus `superuser_reserved_connections` is the maximum for the sum of all non-superuser connections to all databases in the cluster.
2. If you want to limit the number of users per database, setting the limit on the database seems like the obvious choice, right?
3. If you end up setting `max_connections` to a high value, consider using a connection pool instead.

Comment: "If you want to limit the number of users per database, setting the limit on the database seems like the obvious choice, right?" So the role `rolconnlimit` has to be set higher or -1 than the `datconnlimit` to ensure access?

Comment: If you don't want to limit the number of connections per user, leave `rolconnlimit` at `-1`.